# How to dynamically bind angular js imageurls to fabric js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, fabricjs

**Context**

I am working on project in which I am using a fabric js canvas to get image in it. If I use an `img` tag with `ng-src="{{image.imageurl}}"` to get images in `angular` it's working fine. But I want to apply same functionality to canvas using `fabric.Image.fromURL` where this `imageurl` should be passed to the fabric images.

**Question**

I want to pass `image.imageurl` value to `javascript` variable so that I can use it in `fabric.Image.fromURL`.